# API to Object (with array) in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm returning data from transportapi.com & loading it into an object, but the data within the json array isn't being included.

The json returned is:

```
{
  "atcocode": "490012745J",
  "smscode": "47889",
  "request_time": "2016-11-11T22:10:42+00:00",
  "departures": {
    "55": [
      {
        "mode": "bus",
        "line": "55",
        "line_name": "55",
        "direction": "Bakers Arms",
        "operator": "TFL",
        "date": null,
        "expected_departure_date": "2016-11-11",
        "aimed_departure_time": null,
        "expected_departure_time": "22:19",
        "best_departure_estimate": "22:19",
        "source": "Countdown instant"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Controller code:

```
var source = "http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stop/490012745J/live.json?api_key=[key]&app_id=[appid]";

Uri sourceUri = new Uri(source);
System.Net.Http.HttpClient sourceClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage sourceResponse = await sourceClient.GetAsync(sourceUri);
var sourceArray = await sourceResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var selections = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(sourceArray);
```

Model class:

```
public class BusDepartures
{
    public string mode { get; set; }
    public string line { get; set; }
    public string line_name { get; set; }
    public string direction { get; set; }
    public string busoperator { get; set; }
    public object date { get; set; }
    public string expected_departure_date { get; set; }
    public object aimed_departure_time { get; set; }
    public string expected_departure_time { get; set; }
    public string best_departure_estimate { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
}

public class Departures
{
    // First attempt, use BusDepartures object.
    //public List<BusDepartures> BusDepartures { get; set; }

    // Second attempt (as "55" is an array), use array, then convert to object later.
    public string[] routes { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string atcocode { get; set; }
    public string smscode { get; set; }
    public string request_time { get; set; }
    public Departures departures { get; set; }
}
```

Within the Departures class I did try and create a BusDepartures object to store the details of the departures, but I wondered whether, as it is an array, I should use the routes array instead? However when stepping through the code, the BusDepartures object (when it was uncommented) and the routes array were both null.

Any ideas? What am I missing?

**Update:**

Thanks to botond.botos  for the answer. I amended my class to

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string atcocode { get; set; }
    public string smscode { get; set; }
    public string request_time { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<BusDepartures>> departures { get; set; }
}
```

and it worked.

Comment: `"departures": {"55": [{ ... }]` cannot bind to a model - it would mean `Departures` could need a property named `55` which is invalid. If it was `"departures": {"BusDepartures": [{ ... }]` then it would bind to `public List<BusDepartures> BusDepartures { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need the `Departures` class, and try to change the `RootObject` class the following way:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string atcocode { get; set; }
    public string smscode { get; set; }
    public string request_time { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<BusDepartures>> departures { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your trying to map the property name "55" to a non-existent c# property. Either modify the json (which i'm assuming you can't) or use a more generic property to handle the departures.

I'm thinking maybe something like a generic Dictionary(Of int, List(of Departure)) .... which is of course vb and I'm going to guess at new Dictionary<@int, List>() in c# ? :)

```
public class departures {

    public Dictionary<int, List<Departure>> BusDepartures {get; set; }
}
```